# Variables not expanded in Maven plugin

Tags: maven-2, maven-assembly-plugin

In my maven plugin I have the following:

```
<dependencySets>
    <dependencySet>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <outputDirectory>/dir/${project.parent.artifactId}-${project.version}/${project.artifactId}/lib</outputDirectory>
    </dependencySet>
</dependencySets>
```

When `mvn clean package` is run, the `outputDirectory` is literally `dir/${project.parent.artifactId}-${project.version}/...` That is, the variables aren't being expanded. I am not getting any kind of `variable not found` message (nor should I). What could cause variables not to be expanded?

Answer (score 2):

Can you check if the following works?  Essentially, removing the `project` prefix from the variable names, since maven2 is not strict about this.

```
<outputDirectory>/dir/${parent.artifactId}-${version}/${artifactId}/lib</outputDirectory>
```

You may also want to check if you are using the last [maven assembly plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/)